# Which ascii code is this symbol?

Tags: excel, vba, ascii

[image]

I have this symbol on a text file but I need its code to find it with vba app on excel, do somebody knows the ascii of this?

Comment: Do you mean the [gender symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_symbol)?

Comment: This is not ASCII, it is one of UNICODE but I don't know which.

Comment: why haven't you copy&pasted the symbol? into google?

Comment: Unicode codepoint is U+2640 ( female sign ). For the sake of completeness, related symbols are U+2642 ( male sign ). and U+26A5 ( male female sign ).

Comment: looks like messed up cross between [venus symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_symbol) `♀` and [ankh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankh) `☥`

Comment: was the female sign, thanks @collapsar

Comment: "symbol in a text file" implies you know the encoding of the text file. I suspect you don't and therefore have data loss. Whatever viewer is showing you ♀is guessing, since it doesn't have that crucial information either. You most likely have a byte with the value of 12, but which encoding put the 12 in the file? If we assume CP437 then, yes, it is a ♀, but if it is one of many other encodings, it would be Form Feed (␌). _There is no text but encoded text._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, there is the `AscW` function that returns the Unicode code point for the first letter of a string as a decimal number.

Use the following code snippet as an example:

```
Sub mycode()
    MsgBox "female symbol code = " & CStr(AscW(Cells(1, 1).Text)) & ", male symbol code = " & CStr(AscW(Cells(2, 1).Text))
End Sub
```

Output will be

```
female symbol code = 9792, male symbol code = 9794
```

Enter the respective symbols in the Cells A1, A2 of the active Worksheet before running that code in the vba editor. You enter these symbols by keeping `Alt` pressed while typing 11 and 12, resp.

**NB**

There is (at least) one 8-bit codepage that supports the male and female gender symbols ( `U+2642` and `U+2640`, resp. ) as `chr(11)` and `chr(12)`, resp.: [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

This seems to be the closest you can get to an ascii representation.

Comment: yes, thank you! I didn't know how to insert the female code, so many documents use this sign as EOF and I had a little headache with this
thanks once again